# music buffering stops while force download box opens

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

I am working on social networking site which has `grooveshark integration` for music and image sharing like Facebook. This is full ajaxify site. So in this site one can listen music and other side he can do the other things like he can share status , upload images , shares link like facebook. When user open any image there is button to download it.My problem is that when i click on download button to download image while music playing, it makes (if i see in the network by inspect element) streaming fails with the partial content (http code 206) as well as the call for download shows canceled but returns the http code 200ok(in the network by inspect element).
 here is code:

```
 if(file_exists($media_name))
 $path='../webroot/img/user_media/original_uploaded_size/'.$user_id;
    else
    $path='../webroot/img/user_media/single_photo_878_549/'.$user_id;

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($media_name));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($path);
```

please help.
If someone not understands please comment i will tell you about my problem...

Comment: why this questions voted down...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using sessions? Try using `session_write_close();` at the end of your request. This will basically finalize the request.